# How to align multiple flex boxes on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, flexbox, erb

I have the following UI:

[image]

And the code for the UI looks like this:

```
            <% @list.each do |gift| %>
                <div style="display:flex; gap:120px; position:relative; right:150px; width:20px;"
                    <% item.each do |k,v|%>
                        <p> <%=v%> </p>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
```

The parent div is a flex box meaning each row is a flex child. I set a gap for each flex item though and that ends up throwing each child element off balance since the length of text affects the gap. How can I make it so each flex item is aligned? Im assuming I would have to get rid of my use of gap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the overflow to stop flex items from growing when text doesn't fit, but also wrap overflowing text to keep it visible.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5rem;
  width: 350px;
}

div p {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p> one </p>
  <p> two </p>
  <p> three </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p> oneone one one one one  </p>
  <p> twotwotwo two two two </p>
  <p> threethreethreethree three </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p> oneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneone </p>
  <p> twotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwotwo </p>
  <p> threethreethreethreethreethreethree </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I added the div closing ">", if you pay attention to your example there is no closing ">" for the div. and also changed the width as it was much smaller than how usual element is.

you can specify how much space each item inside the flex takes, if you want to equally divide the flex then add `flex: 1` for each item inside the flex, or if you want each one to take a specific space use `flex-basis: 200px` or change the value to anything you want.

in your case I belive this will solve your problem:

```
 <% @list.each do |gift| %>
    <div style="display:flex; gap:120px; position:relative; right:150px; width:500px;">
        <% item.each do |k,v|%>
            <p style="flex: 1"> <%=v%> </p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ah that doesnt work

Comment: @ajsoprano i edited the solution, check it out